# Displaying in the tooltip each value along the y axis on hover

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

Recently started using Recharts for charting.
Here is the data that comes from the server. They need to display Barchart.

```
[
    {
        "channel_number": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "date": 100000,
                "consumption": 1231
            },
            {
                "date": 200000,
                "consumption": 1234
            },
            {
                "date": 300000,
                "consumption": 1234
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "channel_number": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "date": 100000,
                "consumption": 800
            },
            {
                "date": 200000,
                "consumption": 823
            },
            {
                "date": 300000,
                "consumption": 1233
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to display each consumption value on the y-axis. That is, so that when hovering over with the mouse, it shows each value. Like this for example

[image]

I get a tooltip where only the total value of consumption is displayed

[image]

My code:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={385}>
              <BarChart height={300} data={newBar}>
                <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
                <XAxis
                  height={32}
                  dataKey="date"
                  allowDuplicatedCategory={false}
                  tickFormatter={(tick) => convertTimestampToDate(tick, 'dd.MM')}
                  angle={90}
                  tick={{ fontSize: '12px', color: '#626C77' }}
                  textAnchor="start"
                />
                <YAxis tick={{ fontSize: '12px', color: '#626C77' }} />
                <Tooltip cursor={false} labelFormatter={() => ''} />
                <Legend
                  align="right"
                  verticalAlign="top"
                  iconSize={6}
                  formatter={(value, entry, index) => (
                    <span style={{ color: '#969FA8' }}>{value}</span>
                  )}
                  wrapperStyle={{ fontSize: '12px', top: -51 }}
                  payload={data?.channel_consumption.map((item: any, index: any) => ({
                    id: item.channel_number,
                    value: `${item.id_channel}`,
                    color: PIE_COLORS[index],
                  }))}
                />
                {newBar.map((el: any, index: any) => (
                  <Bar
                    dataKey="consumption"
                    data={el.data}
                    key={el.channel_number}
                    fill={PIE_COLORS[index]}
                    barSize={8}
                    radius={71.5}
                  ></Bar>
                ))}
              </BarChart>
 </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? How to display each value when hovering over a bar? Probably do something with the coordinates, I can't figure it out